# JTable model populating

Tags: java, swing

My table on the GUI has fields and what I want to happen is when this method is called to make a new row and simply fill in the information. The error is this

> no suitable method found for `getrow`

```
public void UpdateTable()
{
    DefaultTableModel TableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    for(Patient k: PatientList)
    {
        int TableID = k.getAccountNumber();
        String TableName = k.getName();
        int TableAge = k.getAge();
        String TableAddress = k.getAddress();
        String TableSex = k.getSex();
        String TablePhone = k.getPhone();

        //I get the error here
        TableModel.addRow(TableID,TableName,TableAge,TableAddress,TableSex,TablePhone);

        TableView.setModel(TableModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) for `DefaultTableModel#addRow`. `addRow` expects an *array* of `Objects`. You could do:

```
tableModel.addRow(new String[] { tableID, tableName, ... });
```

*Aside*:

- Are you aware that you are setting the model for *every* `Patient`? This will result in the table containing a single row. You probably want to move the call to `setModel` *outside* your `for` loop.
- Java naming conventions indicate that variables names start with a *lowercase* letter making `TableModel` `tableModel`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have done everything you said, the only problem is that it does not update the table even after I use Table.setModel(TableModel); etc

Comment: Are you sure that `patientList` contains `Patient` data? i.e. not empty?

Comment: Yes, i only call the method after I add a patient to the list. The lists and everything else works even displaying patients, I just wanted to add a table view also. Must I update the table or something for it to display?

Comment: Nothing else is needed. Check to see that you are allowing a size for your `JTable` (i.e. check preferred sizes & layout manager) so that it can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code indeed:

```
public void UpdateTable()
{
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)TableName.getModel();
for(Patient k: PatientList)
{
   int TableID = k.getAccountNumber();
   String TableName = k.getName();
   int TableAge = k.getAge();
    String TableAddress = k.getAddress();
    String TableSex = k.getSex();
    String TablePhone = k.getPhone();

    //Add row here.
    tableModel.addRow(new String[]{TableID,TableName,TableAge,TableAddress,TableSex,TablePhone });
   }
}
```

Look at here  [DefaultTableModel.addRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to know about how to use `addRow()` method for `DefaultTableModel`